# a problem with the hard drive has been detected

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

hey i really need some help .this is what happened
my laptop fell(it was running windows 7) and the computer stopped working normally.i decided to connect it to my desktop(which already contained a hard disk) to try and recover the info.i thought since there was two hard disks that i had to use raid instead of ahci. i then changed it back to ahci when i released it was wrong .i detached my desktop hd and booted into live image .but i keep receiving the following text that flashes before the os starts:

> "the following are warnigs that were detected during this boot. these
>   can be viewed in setup on the event log page 
>   WARNING:A problem with the hard drive has been detected."

after i boot i can see the hard disk but i cant access it, i get get this message when i try to :

> "Unable to mount location
>
> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13:
>   ntfs-mst-post-read-fixup-warn:
>
> Record 1 has no FILE magic oxffffffff)
>
> Failed to open inode $MFTMirr: Input/output error
>
> Failed to load $MFTMirr: Input/output error
>
> Failed to mount idev'sda3: Input/output error
>
> NTFs is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault or it's a
>
> SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk on Windows
>
> then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the If parameter is very
>
> important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
>
> it and mount a different device under the Idewmapper/ directory (e.g.
>
> Idev/mapper/nvidia-eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid documentation
>
> for more details."

plz be specific and detailed. thx

Comment: You dropped it and now are getting IO errors?  Then you broke the drive of course.  Check /var/log/syslog or the output of `dmesg` if you want to see more details about the IO errors, and you might look at the SMART health in the disk utility and you'll probably see it reporting a bunch of bad sectors, in which case, it's time for a new drive.

Comment: i checked it and the attributes failing are :reallocated sector count and current pending sector count.
so there is no way to recover the data with software???

Comment: Get another drive and `dd` as much data off the broken drive as you can, then pray that Windows' `chkdsk` can repair it and recover most of it on the new drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate mix of problems. You probably now have 2 sets of errors:

Dropping a running hard drive will potentially cause a hardware problem from the drop, + a soft error as the writing head drags across the platters

Additionally raid is going to have corrupted your partitions/files, on both drives - but the h/w error will only affect the laptop drive.

I would suggest you concentrate initially on retrieving the desktop drive; check your partitions using `parted --list`. If the output looks sensible, run `fsck` on the partitions (you will likely find you have lost your partition structure though). This is really only recoverable if you know the original layout, or it's worth a try of creating one large partition (the whole disk) & just see if it was right..

If not then you will probably want a tool like `foremost` run from a live CD/USB and a spare (USB?) drive - this will recover files from a corrupted drive but loses the filenames.. You can run it over both drives, use `fdupes` to eliminate common files from both. You then get to play the media files, read the text files, renaming as you go.. Long job. You can reinstall your OS's once the files are recovered.

Comment: Additional rescue options using testdisk: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206?s=2|0.0000#286206 .
**Mark**: us old farts should (probably) stop using `fdisk` and start using `parted` as the latter supports GPT whereas the former only supports MBR...